# Looking for a reference about a lemma about an augmentation ideal in a group ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, reference-request

In the following proposition, $G$ is a group, $H$ is a subgroup, and $\omega(H)$ is defined to be the left ideal of the group ring $R[G]$ generated by the set $\{h-1\mid h\in H\}$

> **Lemma:** If $H$ is a finitely generated subgroup of $G$, then $\omega(H)$ is a finitely generated as a left ideal of $R[G]$. Namely if $\langle h_1,\ldots h_n\rangle=H$, it is generated by $\{a-1\mid a=h_i\text{ or } a=h_i^{-1}\text{ for some } i\}$.

In a document I used this lemma, and since it was so simple I just proved it directly.  However, given its simplicity I'm betting I could abbreviate that to a reference. I'm familiar with a great many expositions on group rings, but I haven't been able to find it in print yet.  I'd really prefer just to cite it, if possible.

What's a good citation I can use for this Lemma?

My best bet would be Milies and Sehgal's *Introduction to group rings* since it is very thorough on $\omega(H)$; however, I do not have access to the book anymore (and didn't notice the lemma in there to begin with.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is Lemma 1.1 in Chapter 3 of Donald Passman's book *The Algebraic Structure of Group Rings*.

You only need to let $a=h_i$ in your generating set; the inverse comes for free.

**Edit,** in response to the poster's comment.

It's true that Passman's book assumes the base ring is a field, although the proof is valid over any ring.  As the poster suspected, the result sought, over an arbitrary ring, is Lemma 3.3.2 of Milies and Sehgal, *An Introduction to Group Rings*.

Comment: Sort of... except I remember Passman's book being entirely in terms of $K[G]$ with $K$ a field.   I know that the proof holds mutatis mutandis, and maybe I could just say so.  Could you let me know if you find the more general statement anywhere, too?

Comment: Thanks for finding the second resource! I did not notice your addition until today. You could ping me with an @<username> notification next time to make sure.